# Why does Webpack ignore publicPath?

Tags: webpack

So I'm trying to bundle my Wasm module, using Webpack. Everything compiles nicely, but whenever I test it on my server it looks for the bundle files under http://127.0.0.1:8080/0.bundle.js

I'm not using the webpack Dev server, and I'd rather not change my file structure.

My file structure looks like this:

```
├── assets  
├── index.html  
├── index.js      
├── serialization  
│   ├── pkg  
│   │   ├── dist  
│   │   │   ├── 0.bundle.js  
│   │   │   ├── 3f139ff5ad432befd963.module.wasm  
│   │   │   └── bundle.js
```

Where the `pkg` folder contains my files I want to bundle.

My current Webpack config looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: '../../index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: path.resolve('./serialization/pkg/dist/'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
};
```

Why does Webpack still look for the files directly under localhost, and not in the public path sub directory?

What I'm trying to achieve is my module being loaded under http://127.0.0.1:8080/serialization/pkg/dist/0.bundle.js. Whenever my module is loaded now I get a 404 not found, because it's looking for it directly in my root (http://127.0.0.1:8080/0.bundle.js)

Comment: Can you explain further how you test it? What do you mean by "Webpack still look for the files directly under localhost"?

Comment: @ChunLiu As in whenever I load my module now I get "GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/0.bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)", because it seems to think my module files are directly in the root. I'm testing this using my browser.

Comment: @pr0sp3r0 does following works? may I also ask why you are using `entry: '../../index.js'` as entry when  index.js in the root

Comment: @user158 I'm using the entry '../../index.js', because my module is in the pkg folder, while my entry point, index.js, is two folders up. I think I could have clarified that better in my question.

Comment: @pr0sp3r0 does not following answer fixes your problem?